# How to redirect all the views in django-allauth to homepage/index instead of /accounts/*

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth for user authentication in my django project.

My question is: How do I change the default urls for django-allauth so that all of them point to my websites index/home page?

I was able to display the the login and registration form on the index and they seem to work fine. What I would want is, everything to be on the index page instead of being on /accounts/something.

So for example, when invalid login details are entered, it currently redirects to /accounts/login, I would want it to redirect to the homepage and display any error messages there itself. Same goes for the email confirmation, signup etc.

using RedirectView.as_view in the urls.py for allauth doesn't seem to pass the data in the request.

here is my project's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'instapayback.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('main_site.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    # url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
)
```

I am still new to django, so everyone is kindly requested to be as descriptive as possible. Thanks

Comment: What does your URL configuration look like?

Comment: What does your index template/view look like?

Comment: @rnevius: I updated the question details.

Comment: @Ngenator: I have just imported the login and registration forms from the allauth app and displayed them on my website's index.

Comment: Well, of course your URLs are going to point to `accounts/`...that's how you've configured it: `url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),` I'm not sure how nicely allauth plays with modifying this.

Comment: @rnevius: modifying accounts/ to / would make the URLs something like this: example.com/login. what I want is that all the login and registration should be on the homepage itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is how i got did it. Not (yet) fully tested, but seems to do the job.

### 1) Remove `url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))`

from your urlpatterns (since you will be overriding it).

### 2) Copy url-pattern skeleton from allauth

Go to `\site-packages\allauth\account\urls.py` and copy the urls you need. You may also want to copy urls from `\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\urls.py`, if you are using the social media signups (Facebook etc.)

Paste the patterns to your main urls.py. Your urls.py should look like this:

```
from allauth.account import views as allauth_views

urlpatterns = [
    ....

    url(r"^signup/$", allauth_views.signup, name="account_signup"),
    url(r"^login/$", allauth_views.login, name="account_login"),
    url(r"^logout/$", allauth_views.logout, name="account_logout"),

    url(r"^password/change/$", allauth_views.password_change,
        name="account_change_password"),
    url(r"^password/set/$", allauth_views.password_set, name="account_set_password"),

    url(r"^inactive/$", allauth_views.account_inactive, name="account_inactive"),

    # E-mail
    url(r"^email/$", allauth_views.email, name="account_email"),
    url(r"^confirm-email/$", allauth_views.email_verification_sent,
        name="account_email_verification_sent"),
    url(r"^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$", allauth_views.confirm_email,
        name="account_confirm_email"),

    # password reset
    url(r"^password/reset/$", allauth_views.password_reset,
        name="account_reset_password"),
    url(r"^password/reset/done/$", allauth_views.password_reset_done,
        name="account_reset_password_done"),
    url(r"^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$",
        allauth_views.password_reset_from_key,
        name="account_reset_password_from_key"),
    url(r"^password/reset/key/done/$", allauth_views.password_reset_from_key_done,
        name="account_reset_password_from_key_done"),

    ....
]
```

### 3) Use the "name"s of the urls in your templates

**For example**: For 'login' link use

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
```

I found [this](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app) article also helpful (How to override a view from an external Django app).

Answer (score 0):

In your projects settings.py file you can override that action by setting the below flags to the path u want in the webapp.

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
Default: '/accounts/profile/'
The URL where requests are redirected after login when the contrib.auth.login view gets no next parameter.This is used by the login_required() decorator, for example.

LOGIN_URL
Default: '/accounts/login/'
The URL where requests are redirected for login, especially when using the login_required() decorator.

You can read more about them in Django docs !

Comment: Yeah, but that is when the user successfully logs in. However, when the user doesn't provide the right details, he/she is redirected to example.com/accounts/login and is displayed the error message. What I would want is, that the user gets redirected to example.com with the error messages. Same for the email confirmation messages etc.

Comment: change the "/accounts/login/" in LOGIN_URL to "your path". If you want error messages your html where your leading it to should have option to display form errors which django will throw.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried reading the default template for login URL. If did not have any code for displaying error messages. However, it does display messages on invalid login.